# VBA delete some colons in column

Tags: json, xml, vba, excel

```
//:celebrity/:channel[:id='239']/:linear/:schedules[:scheduleId='TV_239_2036-05-11_03:00:00.000' and :startTime='2036-05-11T03:00:00.000+0000']/:authorization[:linearAuth='false' and :linearSubAuth='false' and :authCode='NA']
```

I have one column with multiple XPaths. I need JSON version for this so I need to delete all colon characters (:) but not in dates (not in scheduleId and startTime). It means delete them only when before colon is: "/" or "[" or " "
How to do that using VBA code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working in `Column A` ,try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Columns("A:A").Replace What:="/:", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart
    Columns("A:A").Replace What:="[:", Replacement:="[", LookAt:=xlPart
    Columns("A:A").Replace What:=" :", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart
End Sub
```

**EDIT1**: Code based on the comment

```
Sub Demo()
    i = WorksheetFunction.Match("iXpath", Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
    Columns(i).Replace What:="/:", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart
    Columns(i).Replace What:="[:", Replacement:="[", LookAt:=xlPart
    Columns(i).Replace What:=" :", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Here, I am searching for `iXpath` in the range `A1:Z1`, you can change this range as required.

**EDIT2**: Code to work on all worksheets

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            i = WorksheetFunction.Match("iXpath", .Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
            .Columns(i).Replace What:="/:", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart
            .Columns(i).Replace What:="[:", Replacement:="[", LookAt:=xlPart
            .Columns(i).Replace What:=" :", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible change it to this: Delete colons in columns where the name of column, for example F1 is: "iXpath"?

Comment: @Michal - By saying `"where the name of column"` what exactly you mean? Is your `Column F` is named `iXpath` or the header for `Coulmn F` is `iXpath` in `F1`?

Comment: I have: A1=iId, B1=iOutput,...E1=iXpath(it can be different, sometimes G1 and so on)....E2, E3, E4 are Xpaths.

Comment: Thanks a lot! btw what do you mean by Replace What:="""*". is it a mistake? why is asterisk there?

Comment: @Michal - Oops! My mistake. Edited my answer.

Comment: how to update it to change iXpath through all worksheets? I used Dim ws As Worksheet -> For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets -> With ws but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
"MyString" is the string with your content
"MyReplacer" is what shoud replace the colons (can be space, nothing or any other character)

```
MyString = "//:celebrity/:channel[:id='239']/:linear/:schedules[:scheduleId='TV_239_2036-05-11_03:00:00."
MyReplacer = " " 'here add what must replace the ":"
MyString = Replace(MyString," :",MyReplacer)
MyString = Replace(MyString,"[:",MyReplacer)
MyString = Replace(MyString,"/:",MyReplacer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this.  I based this on the input shown, so the position of the = may change, there are 2 in the example.

```
Function testReplace(strInput As String) As String

testReplace = Join(Split(strInput, ":"), "") & "=" & Split(strInput, "=")(2)

End Function
```